# All uses of ellipsis

Tags: go

I am learning Go and it seems the ellipsis `...` has at least 3 uses:

```
// #1: Array declarations
a := [...]int{1, 2, 3}

// #2: Variadic parameters
b := func (ints ...int) []int { return ints }(1, 2, 3)

// #3: Slice spread
c := append([]int{}, []int{1, 2, 3}...)
```

Does the ellipsis have other uses than the above 3?

Comment: No. You listed all.

Comment: It is also used in comments and inside strings to indicate an ellipsis. Just out of curiosity: Why not read the language spec to find out the number of ellipsis-uses?

Comment: @Volker: I am reading the language spec. Just wanted to check my results.

Comment: The `go` tool also uses the 3 dots `...` (technically not an ellipsis) as a path wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, these are all 3 use cases in the language, although the `go` tool uses `...` as a path wildcard.